# Error trying to execute service in systemd

Tags: service, debian, sh, systemd

My system version :
`Linux  6.2.15-lux-amd64 #2 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64 GNU/Linux` (debian based system)

I'm basically trying to create a service to execute my python app on starting the desktop,so going straight to point,i basically have my .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=init_todo_app

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/systemd/system/init_script_caller.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script that it execute(init_script_caller.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH_EXEC=/path_to/init.sh
${PATH_EXEC}
```

And finally the init.sh file witch is called in previous script and is inside the app root folder, he starts a virtual environment and executes the app.

```
#!/bin/sh
ACTUAL_FOLDER=/folder/to_app_root

. "${ACTUAL_FOLDER}/env/bin/activate"
python3 "${ACTUAL_FOLDER}/src/main.py" "minimize"
```

```
chmod 755 init.sh
chmod 755 init_script_caller.sh
chmod 755 todo_service.service
sudo cp -p todo_service.service /etc/systemd/system/todo_service.service
sudo cp -p init_script_caller.sh /etc/systemd/system/init_script_caller.sh
systemctl enable --now todo_service.service
```

i gave execute permission to all the files and moved both service and the script that he calls(init_script_caller.sh) to /etc/systemd/system/. But when i try `systemctl status todo_service.service` , i get:

```
todo_service.service - init_todo_app
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/todo_service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-02-18 10:08:43 -03; 7min ago
Process: 293266 ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/systemd/system/init_script_caller.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 293266 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
CPU: 259ms
```

I already tested and i'm able to run everything fine using "./init_script_caller.sh" inside the
/etc/systemd/system/ folder, so i dont get what is problem, neither i find a way to debug this, since the script itself runs fine.

Comment: What is the purpose of init_script_caller.sh? What does it do that could not be done _more reliably_ by systemd itself?

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much a "systemd" problem as it is a "software architecture" problem.

> I'm basically trying to create a service to execute my python app on starting the desktop,so going straight to point,i basically have my .service file:

That's not going to work, because system services run in a different environment than your desktop apps. (It's not Windows 98 anymore!)

- Your desktop apps run under your own user account; services run as 'root' if not specified otherwise – they don't make any assumptions about "currently logged in" user, because there could be less than one, more than one, or indeed a varying number of logged-in users.
- Your desktop apps receive a lot of *environment variables* from your shell (or graphical launcher), the most critical being the ones that specify the address of your "display server" (X11 or Wayland socket). Services do not receive any of them, in part because many of those environment variables don't exist *yet* for multi-user.target (elaborated below).
- At the time services in multi-user.target start, there is no desktop *yet.* Even the graphical login screen (which is a fully separate "desktop" from your own) is started as just another service, so even that isn't guaranteed to be available yet – much less your own desktop, which starts a lot later.
- All of this environment is deliberately not back-propagated to system services when you log in, because the system is architectured to be multi-user from the ground up (hence the "multi-user.target" name!) and there is no single desktop session "blessed" to be the session that system services may access.

  (Compare to Windows, which used to have 'Session 0' and 'Interactive services' back in Windows XP, but deliberately removed that possibility in later versions.)

So as a general rule, **if it needs to be on your desktop, it should not be a system service.**

- If the app needs to start *on login,* don't make it a service – use the "XDG autostart" mechanism by putting a *.desktop file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` or `~/.config/autostart`.
- If the app needs root privileges, use other means of giving it those privileges – most commonly this is achieved by having the GUI *unprivileged,* only calling out to a privileged "helper" process through pkexec, D-Bus, or some other form of IPC.

  (Example: GNOME Disks, which runs unprivileged but calls the UDisks service to create filesystems and do other privileged operations.)